# What is the best option for large FlatList in react native (expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, flatlist, react-native-snap-carousel

Hello I am building an app and was wondering what the best option would be for optimizing a very large flatlist. It will take some time to load each element inside a flatlist since it contains images, a lot of text, etc. Would it be better to use just a plane flatlist or something like react-native-snap-carousel, react-native-reanimated-carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pagination technique to show large data from flatlist. Avoid third party libraries like `react-native-snap-carousel`. It may cause the issues as time passes and can also be the reason for large `apk` or `ipa` size.

Comment: What is pagination technique? Is it ```react-native-pagination```?

Comment: I mean fetch record on the basis of offset and limit through api. Forexample you fetch first 10 record and show to user. After that onEndReached prop of flat-list, you will call again api with 10 more records.

Comment: Aha, you mean I just use a flatlist and cycle through smaller chunks of data?

Comment: Yes.. It would be easy to handle the large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

If your flatlist will have large data, it is adviced to use pagination. You may use in-built Flatlist or packages like `react-native-snap-carousel` or `react-native-reanimated-carousel`. But since your data will have many images that will make the app UX slow if you load them all at once.

Better to use Pagination and use `react-native-fast-image` for faster loading of images via caching.

Comment: Okay, so pagination is for images. Is there a better option for pages without images, but with a lot of text and large components?